# SONARQUBE Analysing my source code as test code incorrectly

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have two projects in Sonarqube 6, one of them is running as expected. The other is analysing, but's classifying the code it discovers as test code.

See the following extract from the logs :

```
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: -------------  Scan XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Excluded sources for coverage:
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO:   **/I*.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO:   **/*DTO.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO:   **/*ViewModel.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO:   **/AssemblyInfo.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO:   **/project.json
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Base dir: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Working dir: C:\agent\_work\12\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal_DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal_9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Test paths: Parameter.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, packages.config
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Index files
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Excluded sources:
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO:   **/Scripts/Global/**/*.*
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: 2 files indexed
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5]
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sonargraph: Skipping project XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants [DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal:DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal:9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5] (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\agent\_work\12\TestResults\LOCAL SERVICE_BUILDBOX1 2016-10-17 16_30_21\In\BUILDBOX1\LOCAL SERVICE_BUILDBOX1 2016-10-17 16_30_06.coveragexml
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: C:\agent\_work\12\TestResults\LOCAL SERVICE_BUILDBOX1 2016-10-17 16_30_21\In\BUILDBOX1\LOCAL SERVICE_BUILDBOX1 2016-10-17 16_30_06.coveragexml
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor (done) | time=62ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Copy-paste detection exclusions:
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z **/stylecop.json
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9305374Z INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
```

See the section :

```
2016-10-17T15:30:45.9139431Z INFO: Test paths: Parameter.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, packages.config
```

The code that is found in this C# project has been marked as test code and therefore hasn't been analysed. What controls this ? How do I reverse the behavior ?

What I find odd is that one project within the solution is analysed correctly :

```
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: -------------  Scan XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Excluded sources for coverage:
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO:   **/I*.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO:   **/*DTO.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO:   **/*ViewModel.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO:   **/AssemblyInfo.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO:   **/project.json
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Base dir: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Working dir: C:\agent\_work\12\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal_DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal_C7028C31-65FE-4DFA-B557-6BC43CBA0B0D
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Source paths: App_Start/BundleConfig.cs, App_Start/DependencyConfig.cs, App_Start/FilterConfig.cs, App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs, App_Start/RouteConfig.cs, App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs, BootStrapper.cs, Common/DistributorContainer.cs, Common/ExceptionHandler.cs, Common/RuleLookup.cs, Constants/PortalConstants.cs, Controllers/AccountController.cs, Controllers/ApplicationController.cs, Controllers/HomeController.cs, Controllers/ManageController.cs, Controllers/ClientDetailsController.cs, Controllers/QuotationController.cs, Controllers/UnderWritingController.cs, Extensions/CustomValidatorExtension.cs, Extensions/HtmlHelper.cs, Extensions/SessionExtension.cs, Extensions/WebViewExtension.cs, Filters/DistributorFilterAttribute.cs, Global.asax.cs, Models/AccountViewModels.cs, Models/Binder/DateTimeBinder.cs, Models/IdentityModels.cs, Models/ManageViewModels.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, Startup.cs, Validators/BenefitParaSubmitViewModelValidator.cs, Validators/ClientViewModelValidator.cs, Validators/CustomValidator/ValidateDate.cs, Validators/ProductBenefitViewModelValidator.cs, Validators/QuotationClientViewModelValidator.cs, Validators/ValidatorFactory.cs, App_Data/RuleLookups.xml, Content/Application/Applications.css, Content/Customer/Customers.css, Content/Distributors/staysure/en-US/css/layout.css, Content/Distributors/staysure/images/DD_Gaurantee.png, Content/Distributors/staysure/images/logo.png, Content/Distributors/staysure/images/logo2.jpg, Content/Distributors/uib/en-US/css/layout.css, Content/Distributors/uib/images/DD_Gaurantee.png, Content/Distributors/uib/images/logo.png, Content/Global/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.css, Content/Global/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap-rtl.css, Content/Global/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css, Content/Global/Css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css, Content/Global/Css/bootstrap/font-awesome.css, Content/Global/Css/branding.css, Content/Global/Css/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css, Content/Global/Css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg, Content/Global/Css/fonts/iconfont.css, Content/Global/Css/fonts/Metrize-Icons.dev.svg, Content/Global/Css/fonts/Metrize-Icons.svg, Content/Global/Css/google/font-family-droid-sans.css, Content/Global/Css/google/font-family-source-sans-pro.css, Content/Global/Css/iconfont.css, Content/Global/Css/Site.css, Content/Global/Css/style.css, Content/Global/Css/styleguide.css, Content/Global/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg, Content/Global/images/arrow-up.jpg, Content/Global/images/arrow-up.png, Content/Global/images/bg/bottom-footer-gradient.jpg, Content/Global/images/bg/green-gradient.gif, Content/Global/images/bg/green-hover.gif, Content/Global/images/bg/header-gradient.jpg, Content/Global/images/bg/nav-gradient.jpg, Content/Global/images/bg/orange-gradient.gif, Content/Global/images/bg/top-footer-gradient.jpg, Content/Global/images/close.png, Content/Global/images/list-icon.png, Content/Global/images/list-ltr.png, Content/Global/images/loader.gif, Content/Global/images/logo.png, Content/Global/images/pdf.png, Content/Global/images/plus.png, Content/Global/images/sort_asc.png, Content/Global/images/sort_both.png, Content/Global/images/sort_desc.png, Content/Global/images/status.gif, Content/Global/images/tables/minus.png, Content/Global/images/tables/plus.png, Content/Global/images/tabs-grad.jpg, Content/Global/images/tabs-passed.jpg, Content/Home/Css/dashboard.css, Content/Quotation/Quotations.css, Content/Quotation/step.css, favicon.ico, fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg, Global.asax, Scripts/Customer/Customers.js, Scripts/Application/Applications.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.dataTables.js, Scripts/Quotation/AcceptPricingTerms.js, Scripts/Global/bootstrap.js, Scripts/Global/bootstrap.min.js, Content/Global/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, Content/Global/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, Content/Global/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff, Content/Global/Css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot, Content/Global/Css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf, Content/Global/Css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff, Content/Global/Css/fonts/FontAwesome.otf, Content/Global/Css/fonts/Metrize-Icons.eot, Content/Global/Css/fonts/Metrize-Icons.ttf, Content/Global/Css/fonts/Metrize-Icons.woff, Scripts/Global/footable.js, Scripts/Global/gauge/justgage.js, Scripts/Global/gauge/raphael.2.1.0.min.js, Scripts/Global/globalize.culture.en-US.js, Scripts/Global/globalize.culture.zh-CN.js, Scripts/Global/globalize.js, Scripts/Global/jquery-1.10.2.js, Scripts/Global/jquery-1.10.2.min.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.hcsticky.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.metadata.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.validate.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.validate.min.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.wizard.js, Scripts/Global/modernizr-2.6.2.js, Scripts/Global/respond.js, Scripts/Global/respond.min.js, Scripts/Home/dashboard.js, Scripts/Quotation/AcceptQuote.js, Scripts/Quotation/ClientDetails.js, Scripts/Quotation/BillingDetail.js, Scripts/Quotation/ConfirmationAndBuy.js, Scripts/Quotation/ContractAndPrice.js, Scripts/Quotation/DeclineOrRefer.js, Scripts/Quotation/FullMedicalReview.js, Scripts/Quotation/MedicalReview.js, Scripts/Quotation/ProductAndBenefit.js, Scripts/Quotation/Quotation.js, Scripts/Home/header.js, Scripts/Quotation/Quotations.js, Scripts/Quotation/SecondClientDetails.js, Scripts/Quotation/TermsAndConditions.js, Scripts/_references.js, StartUp.html, Web.config, Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config, Views/Web.config, Views/_ViewStart.cshtml, Views/Shared/Error.cshtml, Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml, Views/Home/About.cshtml, Views/Home/Contact.cshtml, Views/Home/Index.cshtml, Views/Account/_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml, Views/Account/ConfirmEmail.cshtml, Views/Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml, Views/Account/ExternalLoginFailure.cshtml, Views/Account/ForgotPassword.cshtml, Views/Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation.cshtml, Views/Account/Login.cshtml, Views/Account/Register.cshtml, Views/Account/ResetPassword.cshtml, Views/Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation.cshtml, Views/Account/SendCode.cshtml, Views/Account/VerifyCode.cshtml, Views/Manage/AddPhoneNumber.cshtml, Views/Manage/ChangePassword.cshtml, Views/Manage/Index.cshtml, Views/Manage/ManageLogins.cshtml, Views/Manage/SetPassword.cshtml, Views/Manage/VerifyPhoneNumber.cshtml, Views/Shared/Lockout.cshtml, Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml, Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml, Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml, Views/Home/Dashboard.cshtml, Views/Quotation/NewClientDetails.cshtml, Views/Quotation/NewQuotation.cshtml, Views/Quotation/ProductAndBenefit.cshtml, Views/Quotation/ContractAndPricing.cshtml, Views/Quotation/AcceptQuote.cshtml, Views/Quotation/TermsAndConditions.cshtml, Views/Quotation/QuotationBillDetail.cshtml, Views/Quotation/DeclineOrRefer.cshtml, Views/Quotation/ConfirmationAndBuy.cshtml, Views/UnderWriting/FullMedicalReview.cshtml, Views/UnderWriting/MedicalReview.cshtml, Views/Shared/_ErrorMessage.cshtml, Views/Quotation/AcceptPricingTerms.cshtml, Views/Customer/Customers.cshtml, Views/Quotation/Quotations.cshtml, Views/Application/Applications.cshtml, Views/Quotation/ContractIssue.cshtml, Views/Quotation/SecondClientDetails.cshtml, Views/Shared/_Loading.cshtml, fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff, fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, packages.config, Scripts/Global/jquery-1.10.2.min.map, Properties/PublishProfiles/AutomatedDeployment.pubxml, Properties/PublishProfiles/AutomatedDeploymentFileSystem.pubxml, Scripts/Global/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js, Scripts/Global/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js, Project_Readme.html
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Index files
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Excluded sources:
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO:   **/Scripts/Global/**/*.*
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: 58 files indexed
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: 24 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: All FxCop rules are disabled, skipping its execution.
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=15ms
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5]
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Sonargraph: Skipping project XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5 [DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal:DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal:C7028C31-65FE-4DFA-B557-6BC43CBA0B0D], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5] (done) | time=0ms
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor
2016-10-17T15:30:46.1326703Z INFO: SonarLint for Visual Studio version 1.13.0.0
2016-10-17T15:30:46.2576727Z INFO: 0/36 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:47.2420820Z INFO: 1/36 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\App_Start\DependencyConfig.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:47.2420820Z INFO: 2/36 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\App_Start\FilterConfig.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:47.2420820Z INFO: 3/36 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:47.2420820Z INFO: 4/36 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs
2016-10-17T15:30:47.2420820Z INFO: 5/36 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs
```

......

I thought it might be a project level setting, so I deleted the original SQ project and created a new project. This made no difference. I have tried adding

```
<Property Name="sonar.test.inclusions">file:**/*XXXX.WebApp*Test*/**/*.*</Property>
```

But this made no difference.

So i'm now at a loss to understand what is going on. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have created a new SONAR server instance and still get this issue. 

I have created a new MVC project and analysed it and get a similar result, the sln has three projects, one MVC, one test and one class project. None of it gets analysed.

But straight after I create a new solution a class project and a test project and it analyses as expected.

It  feels like there is a bug in SQ when MVC projects ?!?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm getting closer I feel, the sonar-project.properties file looks to be incorrect. As i'm using the VSTS task, I need to investigate what it's doing.

```
BF14297E-4A17-4869-9612-E3CBB92E573B.sonar.stylecop.projectFilePath=C:\\agent\\_work\\12\\s\\Seeds\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\\solution\\src\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Configuration\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Configuration.csproj

9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7.sonar.projectKey=DigitalDelivery-AdvisorPortal6:9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7
9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7.sonar.projectName=XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants
9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7.sonar.projectBaseDir=C:\\agent\\_work\\12\\s\\Seeds\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\\solution\\src\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants
9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7.sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=C:\\agent\\_work\\12\\TestResults\\LOCAL SERVICE_BUILDBOX1 2016-10-19 08_54_30\\In\\BUILDBOX1\\LOCAL SERVICE_BUILDBOX1 2016-10-19 08_54_15.coveragexml
9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7.sonar.sources=
9E577C4E-1343-4FC4-BC51-CA75DE04C8C7.sonar.tests=\
C:\\agent\\_work\\12\\s\\Seeds\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\\solution\\src\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants\\Parameter.cs,\
C:\\agent\\_work\\12\\s\\Seeds\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\\solution\\src\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants\\Properties\\AssemblyInfo.cs,\
C:\\agent\\_work\\12\\s\\Seeds\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\\solution\\src\\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants\\packages.config
```

Answer (score 0):

And an additional file highlights the issue further. The file 'ProjectInfo.log'

```
Product projects
---------------------------------------
C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.Presentation.MVC5.csproj


Test projects
---------------------------------------
C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Configuration\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Configuration.csproj
C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Constants.csproj
C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\test\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Logging.UTest\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Logging.UTest.csproj
C:\agent\_work\12\s\Seeds\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor\solution\src\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Logging\XXXX.WebApp.Advisor.CrossCuttings.Logging.csproj
```